# CSS background image y repeat in a container

Tags: css, containers

So I'm trying to set up a container with a background image which repeats when other div elements are long enough within the container div. It hopefully won't repeat when the contained divs are short.

However, I cannot get the image to repeat - I think there's something iffy with the way I've coded the #container.

Here's the HTML I have just now...

```
<body>
  <div id=container>
    <div id=textblock>
      <div id=maintext>
        <p>text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here's the CSS...

```
body {
    background-color: #888;
    background-position: top;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#container {
    background-position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 720px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family: Antelope H;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #c60;
    background:url(images/containerback-01.png) repeat-y;
    background-color: #fc6;
}
```

[Here's the site](http://www.deborahmcarthur.com/what/classes) as it is just now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not a css issue.

Simply place a

```
<br clear="all" />
```

after your

```
<div id="mainText"></div>
```

Whenever you use a float you have to use a clear

Comment: The `clear` attribute is deprecated and obsolete in [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/obsolete.html). The correct way is to apply the CSS equivalent: `clear: both`.

Answer (score 2):

This calls for a clearfix! Container elements only know to be as tall as un-floated children elements. Add [this](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) to your css file:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";    
    display: block;    
    height: 0;    
    overflow: hidden;   
}
.clearfix:after {clear: both;}
.clearfix {zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */
```

and change your container div to open with `<div id="container" class="clearfix">`